# CDI Programmatic lookup with a list of @Qualifier

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm searching a way to dynamicaly lookup a CDI bean annotated by a annotations list.
Is there a elegant way to lookup a bean that contains **at least** one value?

Here is my annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE })
public @interface SelectEngine {

    ProfilUser profil();

    Periodicite periodicite();

    int annee();

    @Qualifier
    @Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface List {

        SelectEngine[] values();
    }
}
```

Here an implementation example:

```
@SelectEngine.List({
            @SelectEngine(profil = ProfilUser.CAS, annee = 2016, periodicite = Periodicite.MENSUELLE),
            @SelectEngine(profil = ProfilUser.COMMERCIAL, annee = 2016, periodicite = Periodicite.MENSUELLE)
})
public class MoteurPMCOM2016 implements MoteurPrime<RapportPrimeMensuelle> {
    /*implementation*/
}
```

In my previous version of the app I used the same annotation without profil array and create a @Produces method inside the implemetation like that:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE })
public @interface SelectEngine {

        ProfilUser profil();
        Periodicite periodicite();
        int annee();
}

//The CDI bean implementation    
@SelectEngine(profil = ProfilUser.COMMERCIAL, annee = 2016, periodicite = Periodicite.MENSUELLE)
public class MoteurPMCOM2016 implements MoteurPrime<RapportPrimeMensuelle> {

        //For profil = ProfilUser.CAS I use the same implementation
        @Produces
        @SelectEngine(profil = ProfilUser.CAS, annee = 2016, periodicite = Periodicite.MENSUELLE)
        public MoteurPrime<RapportPrimeMensuelle> forCASProfil( @SelectEngine(profil = ProfilUser.COMMERCIAL, annee = 2016, periodicite = Periodicite.MENSUELLE) engine) {
          return engine;
        }
/*implementation*/
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using @Produces and parsing the annotations at the InjectionPoint.
You will have to programmatically instantiate the implementations though but it is a solution.

An example: https://martinsdeveloperworld.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/injecting-configuration-values-using-cdis-injectionpoint/

Comment: Hum... I use dynamic lookup for those beans, I can't use the .getAnnoted() method but I think I can use .getQualifiers(). I will post my solution soon.